# How to run curl in a subshell

Tags: ruby, curl, slack

I want to notify a Slack channel without using the Slack client (don't ask why):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#Notification Script Test

slack_rooms = [ '#test_channel_notify' ]
slack_token_file = (File.join(ENV['HOME'], '.slack_api_token')
slack_api_token = (File.open(slack_token_file).readlines)[0].chomp
slack_url = "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage"
user = testuser
msg = 'This is a test message send'

data = {
        "token" => slack_api_token,
        "channel" => slack_rooms,
        "text" => msg,
        "username" => user
}

def send_slack_message(data)
    puts %x{curl -k -X POST -d" #{data}" '#{slack_url}'}
end

send_slack_message(data)
```

But I'm getting some strange errors:

```
./Cap2.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'
send_slack_message(data)
```

It was pointed out I was missing a closing `)` after the `slack_token_file` variable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#Notification Script Test

slack_rooms = [ '#test_channel_notify' ]
slack_token_file = (File.join(ENV['HOME'], '.slack_api_token'))
slack_api_token = (File.open(slack_token_file).readlines)[0].chomp
msg = 'This is a test message send'

data = {
        "token" => slack_api_token,
        "channel" => slack_rooms,
        "text" => msg,
}

def send_slack_message(data)
    slack_url = "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage"
    %x{curl -k -X POST -d" #{data}" '#{slack_url}'}
end

send_slack_message(data)
```

Which results in:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  

Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:50 --:--:--     0
```

When I run the script now it hangs on the Curl command. Does anyone have any experience using the Slack API Endpoint?

Comment: I think you're missing a closing ) on the slack_token_file line to close the File.join or just remove the (

Comment: Do an echo in front of the curl, and/or use specify --silent in your curl command (maybe Ruby or curl really doesn't like the silly progress bar info??)

Answer (score 0):

The way you're creating your data being sent doesn't look right. According to [the documentation](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) it should be in JSON format:

```
slack_rooms = ['#test_channel_notify']
slack_token_file = 'slack_token_file'
slack_api_token = 'slack_api_token'
msg = 'This is a test message send'

data = {
  "token" => slack_api_token,
  "channel" => slack_rooms,
  "text" => msg,
}

slack_url = "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage"
%{curl -k -X POST -d" #{data}" '#{slack_url}'}
# => "curl -k -X POST -d\" {\"token\"=>\"slack_api_token\", \"channel\"=>[\"#test_channel_notify\"], \"text\"=>\"This is a test message send\"}\" 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage'"
```

That's what your code is creating.

```
require 'json'
%{curl -k -X POST -d" #{data.to_json}" '#{slack_url}'}
# => "curl -k -X POST -d\" {\"token\":\"slack_api_token\",\"channel\":[\"#test_channel_notify\"],\"text\":\"This is a test message send\"}\" 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage'"
```

That's what Slack's API expects.

Rather than use curl in a sub-shell, I'd recommend taking advantage of one of Ruby's many [HTTP clients](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients).